# String to object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, object

I have a function working fine:

```
function sendLeadData(form) {
    return trk(form, {
        firstName: "pan",
    });
}
```

`{firstName : "Pan"}` = an object. If I set this to a var and pass the var in function that also works fine. But I need to use a string which I am building from some map and pass that. I am getting the string perfect .Code below not working:

```
function sendLeadData(form) {
    //code to get str
    alert("str is "+str);------->prints str perfect,also giving result below
    var obj = JSON.parse(str);//If except str I put JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({firstName:"Pan"})) that work fine
    alert("obj is "+obj);

    return trk(form,
        obj
    );
}
```

str prints "{firstName:"Pan"}". Error is syntax error thrown.

Please help.

Comment: You need to escape your quotes (`"{firstName: \"Pan\"}"`) or use alternate quotes (`'{firstName: "Pan"}'`).

Answer (score 4):

JSON has more strict object representation. The keys also need to be quoted:

```
'{"firstName": "Pan"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var obj = {x: 5, y: 6, apple:0, name:'myname'};
    var objToText = JSON.stringify(obj);
    console.log(objToText);
    
    var text = '{"x": 5, "y": 6, "apple":0, "name":"myname"}';
    var textToObj = JSON.parse(text);
    console.log(textToObj);
```